# ER Model domain In RDBMS

Tags: entity-relationship, rdbms

In ER model a domain is a set of values for an attribute (i.e., the properties or characteristics of entities).  The value set conforms to a common definition for the domain (e.g., type, format, syntax, meaning).
My question are: Is a domain like a check constraint in database?

Answer (score 0):

A domain, as well as defining a set of allowed values, also defines the operation(s) that can be performed on those values. For instance you may define the logical domains

- *EMPLOYEE_NUMBERS* = { n∈Z ∧ 0 <= n <= 99999 }
- *NUMBER_OF_DAYS* = { n∈Z ∧ 0 <= n <= 99999 }

For the *EMPLOYEE_NUMBERS* domain the mathematical operations of addition and subtraction do not make sense, and so are not defined for the domain. However, for the *NUMBER_OF_DAYS* domain these mathematical operations do make sense and are defined.

When coming to implement the logical domain on a physical (SQL) DBMS a check constraint may be used, in addition to the basic data-type definition. This however, only limits the values allowed in a column, not the operations that can be performed. Therefore, you could define columns with check constraints:

- EMP_NO INTEGER(5) CHECK (EMP_NO >= 0 AND EMP_NO <= 99999)
- NO_OF_DAYS INTEGER(5) CHECK (NO_OF_DAYS >= 0 AND NO_OF_DAYS <= 99999)

Although this limits the values that can be stored in these columns in the same way it does not prevent you from summing all the *EMP_NO*s, although the answer obtained has no meaning. Whereas, a sum of *NO_OF_DAYS* may produce a legitimate result.